# Error in librosa.load('path.webm') RuntimeError: File contains data in an unknown format

Tags: python, librosa, webm, soundfile

I am trying to load sound files on a python script.
I installed, loaded the right version of modules, imported successfully librosa and soundfile, and even ffmpeg (which I found was a solution to this same error for mp3 files)

```
import os
import json
from scipy import signal
import librosa

    [...]

y, sr = librosa.load(directory_path + filename + '.webm', mono = True)
```

My code works on notebooks (Kaggle) but somehow, and I can't figure out why, it doesn't work when uploaded on a computer cluster. And I really need the cluster for its computational power/memory. :/

```
The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.8.5/x86_64/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 146, in load
    with sf.SoundFile(path) as sf_desc:
  File "/cluster/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 740, in __init__
    self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
  File "/cluster/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1264, in _open
    _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
  File "/cluster/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 1455, in _error_check
    raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'input/00092.webm': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis_python.py", line 47, in <module>
    y,sr = librosa.load(directory_path + filename + '.webm')
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.8.5/x86_64/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 163, in load
    y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.8.5/x86_64/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 187, in __audioread_load
    with audioread.audio_open(path) as input_file:
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.8.5/x86_64/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py", line 116, in audio_open
    raise NoBackendError()
audioread.exceptions.NoBackendError
```

I perused the internet for a solution but no luck. Thank you for your help in advance.